# What's wrong with this .htaccess file?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a partially working `.htaccess` file and can’t for the life of me figure out what’s wrong.

Here’s the goal: I have `example.com` whose canonical form I want to be `www.example.com`. I have that working okay. I also have a subdomain located in the folder `/lang/chinese` which I want to resolve as `china.example.net`. This works fine too. Lastly I have the (parked) domain `example.net`, which I want to be redirected to `example.com` and to resolve therefore as `www.example.com`.

It’s this last part that doesn’t work. If I put `www.example.net` in my browser, that stays in the address bar.

Here’s the relevant portion of my `.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} china.example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://china.example.com$1 [L,R=301]


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [L,R=301]
RedirectMatch 301 ^/lang/chinese/(.*)$ http://china.example.com/$1


RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example\.net [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,nc,L]
```

Clearly I am doing something wrong here. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show `VirtualHost` config for `domain2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{http_host} ^example\.net [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=permanent,nc,L]
```

the `^` is telling the regex to match against the beginning of the line. So that means you’re never actually searching for “www” there.

I believe you’ll want to change that to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.net [nc]
```

Info from Apache:

- [RewriteRule Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)
- [RewriteCond Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

Comment: Thank you! You are correct. I tested it and it works. I remain ignorant about why though. Since the middle rule works and changes domain1.com into www.domain1.com (even though the rule itself does not mention the characters 'www'), then why does not the same construction (RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com [NC]) that worked there, work when I use it later to refer to domain2.com ? Any unwrapping of that would be appreciated, but thanks again in any case.

Comment: In the case of your second RewriteCondition, you are saying, "anytime the site they are requesting matches *exactly* 'domain1.com', change it to www.domain1.com". The updated version of your third RewriteCondition is saying, "anytime the site they are requesting matches 'domain2.com' OR 'www.domain2.com', change it to www.domain1.com". The inclusion of "(www\.)?" tells the matcher to execute the rule below in the case where www. is present AND in the case where www. is not present.

Comment: For the second rule, in the case of an incoming request for "www.domain1.com", none of your rules match, and the request just goes through normally. In the case of an incoming request for "domain1.com", your second RewriteCond matches, and it is rewritten to "www.domain1.com". basically the second rule doesn't care about www because if it's already there, it just skips the rewrite entirely.